How to add min period in strategy?
In most cases we add min period in Indicators and in strategy's next(), everything is handled properly. But sometimes the strategy is extremely simple so that I don't want to write a indicator for it. In this case how can I mannully add a min period in strategy? Of course, I can create a dummy indicator in strategy's __init__ but this seems not elegant at all. I'm considering is there exist any elegant method?

Hi, aer you working with they Python? Could you please add a minimal reproducible example?
